# Is it possible to make custom computed index field searchable in SXA 1.8

Tags: sxa, solr, azure-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.0 with SXA 1.8. I've got a requirement to search PDF names and it's fields including custom fields (e.g. download title field). When I see the Solr index / Azure index, PDF names and its fields are not indexing into the SXA AggregatedContent computed index field. So, I've decided to add a custom computed index field and populated the content. But, I didn't find a way to make this computed index field content searchable. I tried to do it through Scope query and rules, But no luck.

Here is the process I'm following,

1. Add a custom computed index field.
2. Add the configuration as
   `<field fieldName="_mediadownloadtitle" returnType="text" patch:source="brand.Foundation.Search.config"&gt;
   brand.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.MediaDependentIndexField, brand.Foundation.Search
   </field>`
3. Add the Boosting rule and the scope query, Both are not satisfactory. Tried all combinations
   [image]
4. Search query from log:

`(((((((-hide_from_search_b:(True)  *:*) AND _mediadownloadtitle_t:("test1234")) AND ((_path:(8e4103c8302c43b197aae65ef11fe4e1) AND searchable_b:(True)) OR _path:(525bed7f6ddb4d5c8a338f3bbc44de46))) AND sxacontent_txm:(*test1234*)) AND _language:(en)) AND _latestversion:(True)) AND ((_mediadownloadtitle_t:(test1234))^90 OR (-_name:("")  _name:[* TO *])))`

As the "sxacontent_txm" index field is applying with AND condition, So, it's not able to show any results even though its building a query for custom index field in Boosting rule or query builder.

Is there a way to make custom computed index field's content searchable in SXA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the computed index will searchable in your case, by default SXA use a computed field `sxacontent` which use following implementation -

```
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent
```

using following config node -

```
<field fieldName="sxacontent" returnType="textCollection" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search">
```

If you want to add your custom implementation to include something in this by overriding the above config node.

Comment: Thank you it worked by overriding the AggregatedContent field.